# Hiding some URL parameters, but not all (with .htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, url-rewriting

I have URL like that

```
  test/users?p=show
```

and i made it to be like

```
test/users/show
```

by using rule:

```
 RewriteRule  ^users/(\w+)$      users.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Parameter **p** could be different and it contains words as arguments, but i would like to add some additional parameters to it in some situations. When im using

```
  test/users?p=show&wg=1
```

it works, but i'd like to work it with

```
test/users/show&wg=1 or test/users/show?wg=1
```

How to achieve that effect ??

Is it even possible to add parameters with **&** to already made rule like that (it could be 1 to 4 additional parameters) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add `QSA`:

```
RewriteRule  ^users/(\w+)$      users.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then it will also pass your parameters into query string.